# How can I use TokenAuthentication and HasAPIKey together in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have an APIView that works exactly how I need it to - I can make a request to it using a tool like Insomnia and/or I can make a request to it by clicking a button from the django website the API is part of.

All work fine, however, I need to add security to it so that if a user makes a request from Insomnia, command line etc., they need to provide an API Key in the Authorization header, or if they click the button they need to be logged in and have a Token.

See my settings.py file below:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ],

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],

}
```

If I remove `'rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey'` then the button works fine and a user is able to make a request to the API with it (as long as they pass the token checks etc of course).

If I ONLY have `'rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey'` in the settings then a user can make a request from Insomnia (or anywhere else) as long as they provide a valid API Key in the header, of course. (But then obviously the call from clicking the button doesn't work)

However, I want to be able to implement both securities measures without having to have both pass but as long as one passes then the call can be made. How do I do this?